# Not able to create new project in node

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am trying to add a new project in angular. Everything is fine till yesterday but as i am doing it today while creating new project i can see nod_modues folder is missing and i am getting below errors

[image]

[image]

i have tried every possible solutions availbale like clearing cache etc but none works pls let me know what exactly is the issue

**Note :** when i am checking versions i am getting below outputs

**node - v**
v10.16.0

**npm -v**

```
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! Callback called more than once.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-02T03_26_05_348Z-debug.log
6.9.0
```

**ng version**

```
Angular CLI: 8.1.2
Node: 10.16.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.801.2
@angular-devkit/core         8.1.2
@angular-devkit/schematics   8.1.2
@schematics/angular          8.1.2
@schematics/update           0.801.2
rxjs                         6.4.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reset the environment variable. Please refer [this](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

Answer (score 0):

**If node_module missing from your current project, then it will not work.
You have two options**

*1. Install again NPM and other dependencies which you have installed in the current project. check all installed dependencies in your JSON file.*

*2. OR Create a New Project as the same name and set up it. and generate all component which you have in your current project after that copy-paste of components codes in the same files in your new project.*